# Avro schema - map type as optional field

Tags: avro

How do I set the arrayofmap in avro schema as optional field. The below schema is working, however, if this field is missing in the data, then the parsing is failing with `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Error converting field - quantities and.`Caused by: `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected array-start. Got VALUE_NULL` 
` I just want to make sure the deserialization of data goes through whether the field is present in the data or not.

```
{
         "name":"quantities",
         "type":{
            "items":{
               "type":"map",
               "values":"string"
            },
            "type":"array"
         },
         "default" : null,
      }
```

Comment: Just found a solution myself. this will make the array of map fields optional in the avro schema

```
{
         "name": "quantities",
         "type": ["null",
             {
                 "type": "array",
                 "items": {
                  "type": "map",
                     "values": "string"
                 }
             }
         ],
         "default": null,
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a solution myself. this will make the array of map fields optional in the avro schema

```
{
         "name": "quantities",
         "type": ["null",
             {
                 "type": "array",
                 "items": {
                  "type": "map",
                     "values": "string"
                 }
             }
         ],
         "default": null,
      }
```